# The concept of differential and derivative

Tags: calculus, analysis, multivariable-calculus, derivatives, terminology

The concept of derivative and differential has always caused me confusion. So, I was reviewing analysis of several variables, and in a book I found the following definition

> Let $X, Y$ be Banach space, $U\subset X$ an open set and $f: U\to Y$ an application, differentiable at a point $a\in U$. The (unique) linear application $A: X\to Y$, which satisfies \eqref{eq1} is called the **derivative of $f$ at point $a$**, denoted by $df(a):= A: X\to Y$. If $f$ is
> differentiable at any point in $U$, then the application
> $$df:U\to\mathcal{L}(X,Y) \qquad a\mapsto df(a)$$ is called the
> **differential of $f$**.
>
> $$\forall\;\varepsilon>0\;\exists\:\delta>0\;\forall\: h\in X, \text{ such that } 0<\left\lVert h  \right\lVert_{X}<\delta \Rightarrow a+h\in U \text{ and } \frac{\left\lVert f(a+h)-f(a)-Ah \right\lVert_{Y}}{\left\lVert h\right\lVert_{X}}<\varepsilon\tag{1}\label{eq1}$$

Through the site there are several posts about the difference between derivative and differential, to to quote a few (as a reference):

[What is the practical difference between a differential and a derivative?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/23902/what-is-the-practical-difference-between-a-differential-and-a-derivative) 
[Differential vs Derivative](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3235946/differential-vs-derivative)
[Are the differential and derivative of a single-variable function exactly the same thing?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/597042/are-the-differential-and-derivative-of-a-single-variable-function-exactly-the-sa)

But despite the good answers, I was still having trouble understanding the difference between these two concepts, until I came across the definition above. So, I would like to see if I really understand these concepts (my interest is restricted to functions $f:\mathbb{R}^m\to\mathbb{R}^n$). I thought of the following example:

Let $f:\mathbb{R}^2\to\mathbb{R}^2$, be defined by $f(x,y)=e^x(\cos y,\sin y)$. So, the **differential** is given by

$$df:\mathbb{R}^2\to\mathcal{L}(\mathbb{R}^2 ,\mathbb{R}^2)\quad\text{where}\quad df=
    \begin{pmatrix}
    e^x\cos y & -e^x\sin y \\
    e^x\sin y & e^x\cos y \\
    \end{pmatrix}
$$

And the **derivative** "*only makes sense*" to speak, when talking about a derivative at a point, so, considering the point $(0,2\pi)$, the **derivative at this point** is given by

$$df(0,2\pi)=
    \begin{pmatrix}
    1 & 0 \\
    0 & 1 \\
    \end{pmatrix}
$$
which is a linear transformation from $\mathbb{R}^2$ to $\mathbb{R}^2$.

I would like to know if my example is correct, that is, if I managed to understand the difference between these concepts.

Comment: In (1), you probably mean $a+h \in U$. And in your example, I would write it as $df_{(x,y)}$ being equal to that matrix (of course keeping in mind the relation between matrices and linear operators).

Comment: @peek-a-boo yes

Comment: They are just distinguishing a function and the evaluation of a function. For example, $\sin$ represents the function but $\sin x$ is the evaluation of $\sin$ at $x$.

Comment: @copper.hat So, am I correct in my interpretation?

Comment: I believe so. ${}$

Comment: Somewhat related too: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3379173/

Comment: I agree with what's written here. Your derivative at a point and your differential are correct, though I might still call the map $df$ the "derivative of $f$" so the terminology isn't clear cut

Comment: I am skeptical that this distinction between derivative and differential is actually all that widespread, I’ve always used the terms more or less interchangeably, and added “at a point” (or otherwise clarified via notation) to specify if I am talking about the evaluation at a specific point.

Comment: I personally like to distinguish between the differential $\mathrm df$ and "a derivative" by saying that a *derivative for $f$* is some function $D$ such that for some fixed bilinear function $M$ we have $\mathrm df(x)(h) = M(D(x), h)$. In other words, a derivative is something you "multiply by" to get the differential. This is consistent with your definitions above by taking $M$ to be matrix multiplication, and is also consistent with the term "derivative" used in single-variable real and complex analyis as well as when it's used for various "matrix derivatives".

Answer (score 4):

It seems there is **no general clear separation** of the term *differential* from the term *derivative*. Some authors distinguish between these terms, others do not. Here are two examples:

**R. Courant:** *[Introduction to Calculus and Analysis, I and II](https://link.springer.com/book/10.1007/978-3-642-58604-0)*

R. Courant clearly separates these terms and provides a detailed and careful explanation already in the one-dimensional case. In section 2.8 (j): *The Approximation of Functions by Linear Functions. Definition of Differentials* the author defines the differential as the *dominant linear* part with respect to the increment $\Delta x$.

> **From section 2.8 (j):**
> The derivative of a function $y=f(x)$ was defined by
> \begin{align*}
> f^{\prime}(x)=\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{f(x+h)-f(x)}{h}=\lim_{\Delta x\to 0}\frac{\Delta y}{\Delta x}
> \end{align*}
> where $\Delta x=h$. If for a fixed $x$ and a variable $h$, we define a quantity $\varepsilon$ by
> \begin{align*}
> \varepsilon(h)=\frac{f(x+h)-f(x)}{h}-f^{\prime}(x)=\frac{\Delta y}{\Delta x}-f^{\prime}(x),
> \end{align*}
> then the fact that $f^{\prime}(x)$ is the derivative of $f$ at the point $x$ amounts to the equation
> \begin{align*}
> \lim_{h\to 0}\varepsilon(h)=0
> \end{align*}
> The quantity $\Delta y=f(x+h)-f(x)$ represents the change or *increment* in the value of the dependent variable $y$ that results when the value $x$ of the independent variable is changed by the amount $\Delta x=h$. Since
> \begin{align*}
> \Delta y=f^{\prime}(x)\Delta x+\varepsilon \Delta x,
> \end{align*}
> the quantity $\Delta y$ appears as the sum of two parts, namely, a part $f^{\prime}(x)\Delta x$ which is proportional to $\Delta x$ and a part $\varepsilon \Delta x$ which can be made as small as we please compared to $\Delta x$ by making $\Delta x$ itself small enough. The dominant, linear part in the expression for $\Delta y$ we shall call the **differential** $dy$ of $y$ and write for it
> \begin{align*}
> dy=df(x)=f^{\prime}(x)\Delta x\tag{2}
> \end{align*}

Some more detailed information also about the two-dimensional case is given in *[this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2954581/differentials-in-multivariable-calculus/2955702#2955702)*.

**W. Rudin:** *[Principles of Mathematical Analysis](https://maa.org/press/maa-reviews/principles-of-mathematical-analysis)*

On the other hand there is a remark by W. Rudin in his *Principles* clearly indicating the other direction. We find the definition of *Derivative* in section 9.11:

> **From section 9.11:**
> **Definition** Suppose $E$ is an open set in $\mathbb{R}^n$, $\mathbf{f}$ maps $E$ into $\mathbb{R}^m$, and $\mathbf{x}\in E$. If there exists a linear transformation $A$ of $\mathbb{R}^n$ into $\mathbb{R}^m$ such that
> \begin{align*}
> \lim_{\mathbf{h}\to\mathbf{0}}\frac{|\mathbf{f}\left(\mathbf{x}+\mathbf{h}\right)-\mathbf{f}(\mathbf{x})-A\mathbf{h}|}
> {|\mathbf{h}|}=0,\tag{14}
> \end{align*}
> then we say that $\mathbf{f}$ is *differentiable at* $\mathbf{x}$, and we write
> \begin{align*}
> \mathbf{f}^{\prime}(\mathbf{x})=A.
> \end{align*}
> If $\mathbf{f}$ is differentiable at every $\mathbf{x}\in E$, we say that $\mathbf{f}$ is *differentiable in* $E$.

This section is followed by section 9.13 *Remarks* where remark (a) and (d) are of interest for us. Here the author explicitly states that derivative and differential are sometimes used interchangeably.

> **From section 9.13 (a) and (d):**
>
> - *Remark (a):* The relation (14) can be rewritten in the form
>   \begin{align*}
>   \mathbf{f}(\mathbf{x}+\mathbf{h})-\mathbf{f}(\mathbf{x})=\mathbf{f}^{\prime}(\mathbf{x})\mathbf{h}+\mathbf{r}(\mathbf{h})
>   \tag{17}
>   \end{align*}
>   where the remainder $\mathbf{r}(\mathbf{h})$ satisfies
>   \begin{align*}
>   \lim_{\mathbf{h}\to\mathbf{0}}\frac{|\mathbf{r}(\mathbf{h})|}{|\mathbf{h}|}=0.\tag{18}
>   \end{align*}
> - *Remark (d):* The derivative defined by (14) or (17) is often called the *differential* of $\mathbf{f}$ at $\mathbf{x}$, or the *total derivative* of $\mathbf{f}$ at $\mathbf{x}$, to distinguish it from the partial derivatives that will occur later.

Comment: @vallev: Many thanks for granting the bounty. :-)